# Popping out images on transparent background Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to get images similar to www.eskimodesign.com.au or facebook where you click on a photo and it pop outs and darkens the background.

(Try clicking on a project or image on the eskimo website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out

1. [**Lightbox**](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
2. [**Fancybox**](http://fancybox.net/)
3. [**Thickbox**](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)
4. [**Slimbox**](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox)

Check this out too: [**Rounding Up the Top 10 jQuery Lightbox Scripts**](http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, looks like you're looking for a lightbox component.
There are a lot out there each to their own design.

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

You'll need to have jquery enabled while using this as well.

http://jquery.com/

Some other lightboxes

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/

http://fancybox.net/